# ValueError: could not convert string to float - sns.tsplot, time - using strings to label x axis

Tags: python, time-series, seaborn, axis-labels

file 'input' (wrong columns, which is why I use header =0 in `read_csv`)

```
meter   overnight   breakfast   daytime evening std-year    season-score    week-score
0   1002.0  0.56    1.16    1.14    1.32    5.04    0.5 1.26
1   1003.0  0.74    0.96    0.87    1.44    2.62    0.19    1.08
2   1004.0  0.65    0.53    0.85    1.71    3.32    0.48    0.36
3   1005.0  0.49    1.22    1.09    1.42    3.57    0.56    2.54
4   1008.0  0.87    0.76    0.95    1.28    3.36    0.42    1.69
```

code

```
toc = time.time()
#header = 0 replaces the headers with names specified
read = pd.read_csv('input', sep='\t', index_col= 0, header =0, names =['meter', 'overn_PR', 'breakf_PR', 'day_PR', 'evng_PR', 'std_year', 'week_score', 'season_score'], encoding= 'utf-8')
read.drop('meter', 1, inplace=True)
read['std_year'] = round(read['std_year']/4, 2)
print(read.columns.values.tolist())

input = read.as_matrix()

sns.tsplot(data=input, err_style='unit_traces',\
       value = 'energy use [kWh]',\
        time = read.columns.values.tolist())
plt.show()

tic = time.time()
print(tic-toc)
```

[image]
Currently the plot only shows numbers in sequence along the x axis.
It's not entirely correct to label y axis as what's shown currently as the values corresponding to x = 4, 5, 6 are standard deviations.. but leaving that aside, is there a way to label x axis with strings? I noticed it is possible to do so with date/times.

Following are the error I receive at the moment. It is odd that the ValueError would be incurred at the 6th item of the `read.columns.values.tolist()` list..but nonetheless this is not working. Has anyone got insight into the matter? I'd deeply value, thanks.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hsl/work_dir/eclipse/ISSDA/src/GMM_ppr.py", line 32, in <module>
  time = read.columns.values.tolist())
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/seaborn/timeseries.py", line 280, in tsplot
  x = df_c.columns.values.astype(np.float)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'week_score'
```

Comment: could you add a few lines of the CSV so one could replicate the issue ?

Comment: thanks for the idea. I updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time just didn't accept the strings in the list.
I did find a workaround using *xticks* in order to use strings as labels for the x-axis.

```
toc = time.time()
#header = 0 replaces the headers with names specified
read = pd.read_csv('input', sep='\t', index_col= 0, header =0, names =['meter', 'overn_PR', 'breakf_PR', 'day_PR', 'evng_PR', 'std_year', 'week_score', 'season_score'], encoding= 'utf-8')
read.drop('meter', 1, inplace=True)
read['std_year'] = round(read['std_year']/4, 2)
print(read.columns.values.tolist())

input = read.as_matrix()
string_val = read.columns.values.tolist()

sns.tsplot(data=input, err_style='unit_traces',\
       value = 'energy use [kWh]')
plt.xticks(range(7),string_val) #sets the x axis with the supplied list

plt.show()

tic = time.time()
print(tic-toc)
```